# How using data of current model into current model :)

Tags: django, django-models, path, imagefield

Hiii every one.
I am new to Django and start to create a basic project
and now i have a problem with ImageField and Upload_To

i have a model that have some field, like (car_name) and (photo) and i called that "Cars"

admin can create a new car and select an image
and
type a name for that car

then admin hit save button
and now image should save somewhere
I want to save that image into this path:
photos/Cars/???car_name???

my question is: how get the name of car and use that name to use in ((upload_to = path))?

im really sorry if i have writing issue

This is my code:

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    car_name= models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"photos/Cars/{car_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(instance.first_name, filename)

class Cars(models.Model):
    car_name= models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

this worked to me